# How to get errorbars and roller window in dygraphs when using an array as the input?

Tags: javascript, html, time-series, dygraphs

I have the following code which generates a dummy time series chart using dygraphs:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv3"
  style="width:1000px; height:600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g3 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
    [
                [new Date("2009/07/12"),10,100],
                [new Date("2009/07/13"),20,80],
                [new Date("2009/07/14"),70,80],
                [new Date("2009/07/15"),50,60],
                [new Date("2009/07/16"),10,100],
                [new Date("2009/07/17"),20,80],
                [new Date("2009/07/18"),50,60],
                [new Date("2009/07/19"),70,80],
                [new Date("2009/07/20"),10,100],
                [new Date("2009/07/21"),20,80],
                [new Date("2009/07/22"),50,60],
                [new Date("2009/07/23"),70,80]
              ],
              {
                labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ]
                
    }
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I use errorBars: true, or
showRoller: true,

the chart does not render.

Can someone please help me with this?

The errorBars and showRoller works fine when I use a csv input.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem with `showRoller`:

```js
  g3 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    [
      [new Date("2009/07/12"),10,100],
      [new Date("2009/07/13"),20,80],
      [new Date("2009/07/14"),70,80],
      [new Date("2009/07/15"),50,60],
      [new Date("2009/07/16"),10,100],
      [new Date("2009/07/17"),20,80],
      [new Date("2009/07/18"),50,60],
      [new Date("2009/07/19"),70,80],
      [new Date("2009/07/20"),10,100],
      [new Date("2009/07/21"),20,80],
      [new Date("2009/07/22"),50,60],
      [new Date("2009/07/23"),70,80]
    ],
    {
      labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ],
      showRoller: true,
    }
  );
```

([demo](https://jsbin.com/mepiwacufo/edit?css,js,output))

If you want to show error bars, you'll need to use a different data format (since you need to say how large the error bars are for each data point). See the [dygraphs data format](https://dygraphs.com/data.html) documentation for more info.